# How can I compress an image before storing it in MongoDB using GridFS and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I'm trying to upload images in my NodeJS app using GridFS and MongoDB.
I want to compress the image before it is uploaded in MongoDB and I've shared the GridFS middleware.

I would like to know where I should put the compression code or if there is a better way to compress images?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Mongouri = process.env.MONGO_URL;
let conn = Mongoose.connection;
let gfs;
conn.once('open',()=>{
    gfs = Grid(conn.db,Mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('Posts');
});


//defining the middleware for multer so this will be called everytiime a new image is uploaded using multer 
let storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url:Mongouri,
    file:(req,file)=>{
        return new Promise(
            (resolve,reject)=>{
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename:Mongoose.Types.ObjectId()+file.originalname,
                    bucketName:"Posts"
                };
                resolve(fileInfo);
            }
        );
    }

});


//initialising multer with the middleware 
const upload = multer({storage});

module.exports = upload;
```

Comment: Do you know roughly how large these images would be?  In particular, what is the largest image size you expect here?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen 1 MB is the maximum a user can upload but i want it to be  compressed when stored

Answer (score -1):

Sharp is a better tool to compress the images before you save them in DB. Source - [Sharp npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp)

Comment: Where do i include the sharp code like should i use it in the middleware itself or in the route

Comment: Can you please tell the best practise to compress images and store them in the Database?

Comment: Hi. This piece of code will help you to understand how to use it. Don't copy and paste it, as it will not gonna work. The purpose is to show how to use the Multer and Sharp modules to upload images to the DB. Here is the link to the code [pastebin link](https://pastebin.pl/view/28636842)